# Sync mobile website to main website

Tags: mobile, synchronization, html-content-extraction

I am building mobile websites for my clients.  A large company offer autosync between the mobile and main site so that when an image or text is updated on the main site the mobile site is updated automatically. I would like to offer the same feature.  I will not have access to main site code, but I can build the mobile site as a dynamic site.  How do I extract/scrape the images and text from main site  and assign them names/values(?) so that my dynamic mobile site is connected to main site.

If I am thinking about this all wrong, please point me in right direction.

Thank You in advance!
Chip